# How to solve $2c x + x\dot x + (c^2-1)t = cd$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

After computation on a certain problem, for a specific case I came across the differential equation $$2c x + x \dot x + (c^2-1) t = cd$$
with initial conditions $0 < x(0) = d $ and  $1 < - \dot x(0) = c $. Does this have a closed form?

This differential equation doesn't appear to conform to solution by factors, integrating factors, Clairaut's equation, homogeneous methods, differentiating methods, Riccati's equation, or any other special form or method I know of.

Comment: If I deleted your comment it was by accident. The initial velocity was missing a minus sign.

Comment: What does $\dot x$ mean? Is that the *derivative* of $x$ (as another user defined $\dot x$ as it's derivative in another post)? If so, then with respect to what value? Sorry if I am a bit amateur at this.

Comment: It is standard notation for a derivative with respect to time, the number of dots being the number of time derivatives. It was invented by Newton.

Comment: Thank you for telling me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2c x + \frac{dx}{dt} x + (c^2-1) t =cD$$
The symbol $D$ is used instead of $d$ to avoid confusion with the differential symbol.
Let $\quad cD=a$
$$2c x + \frac{dx}{dt} x + (c^2-1) t - a=0$$
$y(t)=(c^2-1)t-a  \quad;\quad  \frac{dx}{dt}= \frac{dx}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt}= (c^2-1)\frac{dx}{dy}$
$$2c x + (c^2-1)x\frac{dx}{dy} + y=0$$
$x=yu(y)\quad;\quad \frac{dx}{dy}=u+y\frac{du}{dy}$

$2c yu + (c^2-1)yu(u+y\frac{du}{dy}) + y=0$
$$2c u + (c^2-1)(u^2+yu\frac{du}{dy}) + 1=0$$
$y=e^z$
$$2c u + (c^2-1)(u^2+u\frac{du}{dz}) + 1=0$$
$$\frac{du}{dz} =-\frac{1+2cu}{(c^2-1)u}-u=-\frac{1+2cu+(c^2-1)u^2}{(c^2-1)u}=-\frac{ ((c+1)u+1)((c-1)u+1) }{(c^2-1)u}$$
$$z=(c^2-1)\int \frac{u}{((c+1)u+1)((c-1)u+1)}du+c_1$$
$$z=\frac{1}{2}(c+1)\ln|(c-1)u+1|-\frac{1}{2}(c-1)\ln|(c+1)u+1|+\text{constant}$$
$$y=e^z=c_1\frac{ ((c-1)u+1)^{(c+1)/2} }{((c+1)u+1)^{(c-1)/2}}$$
$$y=c_1\frac{ ((c-1)\frac{x}{y}+1)^{(c+1)/2} }{((c+1)\frac{x}{y}+1)^{(c-1)/2}}$$
$$y^2=c_1\frac{ ((c-1)x+y)^{(c+1)/2} }{((c+1)x+y)^{(c-1)/2}}$$
$$( (c^2-1)t-a) ^2=c_1\frac{ ((c-1)x+(c^2-1)t-a))^{(c+1)/2} }{((c+1)x+(c^2-1)t-a))^{(c-1)/2}}$$
The general solution of the ODE is expressed on the form of an implicit equation (with $a=cD$):
$$( (c^2-1)t-cD) ^2=c_1\frac{ ((c-1)x+(c^2-1)t-cD))^{(c+1)/2} }{((c+1)x+(c^2-1)t-cD))^{(c-1)/2}}$$

Condition $x(0)=D\quad\to\quad (-cd) ^2=c_1\frac{ ((c-1)D-cD))^{(c+1)/2} }{((c+1)D-cD))^{(c-1)/2}}\quad$ After simplification : $c_1=c^2D$
$$( (c^2-1)t-cD) ^2=c^2D\frac{ ((c-1)x+(c^2-1)t-cD))^{(c+1)/2} }{((c+1)x+(c^2-1)t-cD))^{(c-1)/2}}$$
This is the solution of the problem expressed on the form of implicit equation.

In case of first order ODE, only one boundary condition is sufficient. It is up to you to add an extra condition $\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)_{t=0}=-c$. Just test if it is compatible with the solution already found. If not, the problem would have no solution according to two boundary conditions instead of only one.

In the present case, at $t=0$ we have $x=D$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}=-c$. Putting them into the ODE gives : $2cD-cD=cD$ which is correct. So, the extra condition is implicitly satisfied. No need to worry about it.

Comment: I had solved it almost identically taking a linear transformation on time turning it into a homogeneous equation. There is a mistake: you assumed y was greater than zero leading to a different result. Also how did you remove the absolute value bars? I have reason to believe an explicit form exists in terms of special functions.

Comment: The absolute value bars spontaneously disappear when the exponential form is expressed, because the arbitrary constant. For example, from $y=\ln| x|+c_1$ we get $e^y=c_2e^{\ln| x|}=c_2| x|=c_3x$. The arbitrary coefficient implicitly includes the arbitrary sign.

Comment: Of course, one can alternatively change of function $y=-e^z$ or more generally $y=Ce^z$ with arbitrary constant C. The coefficient $C$ disappears in $y\frac{du}{dy}$. Do it and see that the result is the same except that the change of arbitrary constant $c_1$ to arbitrary $c'_1=c_1C$ which finally changes nothing.

Comment: No constant accounts for an x that is both positive and negative. You are correct about the z sign, however where is the carried minus sign in the first integral?

Comment: $x$ is not positive and negative together, except $x=0$. In a range it is positive and you have an arbitrary constant. In another range it is negative and you have another arbitrary constant. But that is equivalent since the constants are arbitrary. This situation is commonly encountered in solving ODEs. About the question of sign in the first integral : If you see a mistake, it's up to you to correct it. I will not spend time to check and correct this detail because the goal here is just to give an hint to help the OP about the method of solving, nothing more.